# Can't connect arduino to IBM IoT platform

Tags: arduino, ibm-cloud, mqtt, ibm-watson

I have been trying to make this tutorial work: https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/arduino-nano-ethernet-shield-and-iot/.

I have done every step but my Arduino nano is not connected. At dashboard Connection Status of device is Disconnected and at serial monitor I have messages Arduino MQTT v, 1, 2, Reconnecting client...

My code is below.

```
#include <UIPEthernet.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

// Update these with values suitable for your network.
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xED, 0xBA, 0xFE, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 1, 200 }; //put your device’s local ip here DA
EthernetClient ethClient;

//char servername[]=”1jyf9u.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com”;
char servername[] = { 141, 125, 70, 157 };
PubSubClient client(servername, 1883, 0, ethClient);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Arduino MQTT v, 1, 2");
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
}

void loop()
{
  //client.loop();
  char clientStr[33];
  String clientName = String("d:1jyf9u:my_nano_type:my_nano_id");
  clientName.toCharArray(clientStr, 33);
  char token[] = "6q_n@g@HjUyQJEv6Nx";
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Reconnecting client … ");
    client.connect(clientStr, "use - token - auth", token);
  }

  String data = "{\"d\": {\"TEST\" : \"";
  data += random(10);
  data += "\" } } " ;  


  char jsonStr[33];
  data.toCharArray(jsonStr, 33);
  char topicStr[33];
  String topicName = String("iot - 2 / evt / status / fmt / json");
  topicName.toCharArray(topicStr, 33);
  Serial.print("attempt to send ");
  Serial.print(jsonStr);
  Serial.print(" to ");
  Serial.println(topicStr);
  if (client.publish(topicStr, jsonStr))
    Serial.println("successfully sent");
  else
    Serial.println("unsuccessfully sent");
  Serial.println("Disconnecting client … ");
  client.disconnect();
  delay(5000);
}
```

I have tried to changed default rule to TLS optional. Also, I tried to change port to 8883 and set up default rule to TLS with Token Authentication but none succeeded.

Any idea/suggestions?

Comment: I see that you are connecting over 1883, did you set TLS Optional in security section of the Watson IoT Platform?

Comment: I'm probably not the best informed about this particular case but you have copied the MAC address from the tutorial, most likely you need to change it to the MAC address of your Ethernet shield

Comment: Thanks for answers. I have tried to set TLS Optional but it did not worked. Also, I found out that I really shouldn't need to "get" the MAC address. It can be anything, but must be unique in my network. I supposed that MAC is not the problem but I change it anyway - did not helped, same issue.